# C++11 equal_to and less

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename C> T pfind(T f, T e, C c){
    do{
        for (int i = 1; f + i != e; i++)
            if (c(*f, *f + i))
                return (f + i);
    } while (++f != e);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int>vstr = { 1, 2, 3, 4,4,5,5,5 };

    vstr.erase(pfind(vstr.begin(), vstr.end(),equal_to<int>()));
    for (auto&itr : vstr){
        cout << itr << " ";
    }
    getchar();
}
```

This code crashes...

But when i tried to use less instead of equal_to its working....

Could anyone please explain me why?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Your function will fail on an empty range. You're also passing the wrong thing into the predicate. Anyway, why not use `std::find_if`?

Comment: It looks like you compiled this code with *warnings disabled*.  Or did your compiler show you warnings?

Comment: It shouldn't even compile, you fail to return anything at the end of the `while`.

Comment: That's a very confusing function. Aren't the two loops redundant?

Comment: are you sure you meant c(*f,*f+i) instead of c(*f,*(f+i))?

Comment: @MarkRansom, While MSVC makes that an error, it's still just a warning on GCC and Clang. Still shouldn't compile cleanly.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: no. It appears to be looking for any two numbers that are the same. It could be more clearly written as two for loops though.

Comment: @sharth, Oh, good point. I fail. I guess you can still use `std::find_if` to search the remaining elements, though.

Comment: main.cpp:13:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: I just couldn't understand the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the comments Alessandro Teruzzi has the key point.

> are you sure you meant `c(*f,*f+i)` instead of `c(*f,*(f+i))`?

But that being said, this could be written more clearly as two nested for loops, and with **longer variable names**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename C> T pfind(T begin, T end, C comparator){
    for (int i = 0; begin + i != end; ++i)
        for (int j = i+1; begin + j != end; j++)
            if (comparator(begin[i], begin[j]))
                return (begin + i);
    return end;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int>vstr = { 1, 2, 3, 4,4,5,5,5 };

    vstr.erase(pfind(vstr.begin(), vstr.end(),equal_to<int>()));
    for (auto&itr : vstr){
        cout << itr << " ";
    }
    getchar();
}
```

We could also write the `pfind()` function directly using iterators:

```
template<typename T, typename C> T pfind(T begin, T end, C comparator){
    for (; begin != end; begin++)
        for (T iterator = std::next(begin); iterator != end; iterator++)
            if (comparator(*begin, *iterator))
                return begin;
    return end;
}
```

Additionally, in both cases there's a chance that we will return the end pointer. If we do, then we will call `vstr.erase(vstr.end())`, which is undefined behavior. So you probably want to check for that.

### Let's talk about what a particular warning means:

In the comments you said that the compiler reported this warning:

```
main.cpp:13:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

It means that the compiler was not able to ensure that all paths through the code would end with a statement `return ...;` In your case, in the simplest case, if `begin == end`, then the first loop will not be entered, and we will hit the end of the function without reaching a `return ...;` statement.

In the code I've posted with fixes, you can see that if we never find a match, we return the  end pointer, which is a common way of reporting no match.

Comment: I would avoid to use `begin` as variable name with `using namespace std`. (ok, In fact, I would avoid `using namespace std`).

Answer (score 2):

If you'd paid attention to the compiler warnings, you'd have had a clue why your function fails. When you pass `std::equal_to` as the comparison predicate, it's not finding a match (due to an error in your code).

In the case where a match isn't found, your function ends without returning anything, which is undefined behavior. The subsequent use of this non-existent return value in the call to `vector::erase` results in the crash.

---

Your code fails to find a match because of this condition:

```
if (c(*f, *f + i))
```

You're first dereferencing the iterator and then adding `i` to that result. What you actually want to do is

```
if (c(*f, *(f + i)))
```

And then add a return statement at the end of the function for the case when a match is not found.

```
return e; // return the end iterator
```

---

Finally, your entire function can be replaced by [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) which searches a range for two adjacent elements that meet a specified criterion. The two argument version uses `operator==` to perform the comparison, while you can supply a binary predicate using the three argument version. Using this, your example reduces to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>vstr = { 1, 2, 3, 4,4,5,5,5 };

    vstr.erase(std::adjacent_find(vstr.begin(), vstr.end()));
    for (auto&itr : vstr) {
        cout << itr << " ";
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1 2 3 4 5 5 5

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5979698882b0a986)